# if selector not available (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

When the selector is not available, i will get a this error:

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null"

This my code:

```
if (page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#primaryStatus').innerText) !== null) {
  const primarStatus = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#primaryStatus').innerText);
}
```

How can i change this?

Comment: Formatted text and code

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLElement object itself would be null. I would try replacing your first line with `if (page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#primaryStatus') !== null){
/*rest of your code*/}`